# How can I make the dependencies not upload to the company 's internal repository?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

My `pom.xml` use the following code to define the company 's internal Maven repository  such that  the dependencies will be downloaded from this repository if they cannot be found in my local repository.

```
<repositories>
            <repository>
               <id>XXXXXX</id>
               <name>Internal Repository</name>
               <url>http://private.ip/nexus-webapp/content/groups/public/</url>
            </repository>
</repositories>
```

When I add some dependencies in `pom.xml` , I find that the dependencies I added will also be added to that internal  repository  . Besides deleting  `<repositories>` section in `pom.xml` , can I configure its attributes such that  the dependencies added  in the  `pom.xml`  will not be added to this internal repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're talking about is Nexus' proxying mechanism. You request artifacts from Nexus, and it looks at configured outside repos for the artifacts, caches them locally and returns them to you. That assumes the repositories in question are configured to be proxied through Nexus, of course. If someone set it up that way, then why do you want to circumvent it? You'd use Nexus in this way so the artifacts are closer to you and your builds work faster. The only way you'd get this not to happen is to change the settings in Nexus or else stop using it. You don't have to remove the repo entirely from the pom. Just put other repos ahead of it, and Maven will look in those first. But again, why would you not want to use Nexus as it was designed as a near cache for artifacts?

Comment: Because I want to download some jars to my local repository for testing first .Once I confirm to use them in the project , I will upload to that Internal Repository to prevent it from having many unused jars.

Comment: Originally , I think that internal repository just like a share drive which store some jars in order to speed up developers to download the necessary jars faster. The jars in that internal repository  are required to be uploaded by the repository admin manually .But from your comment , the internal repository actually is a proxy .If the  `<repositories>` section in pom.xml  is specified ,  all the requests sent out and returned jars will be through these repositories.

Comment: So if I don't want the jars to be added to the  internal repository , the only ways are to not use the proxy by removing  the `<repositories>` section in pom.xml  or configure the sever side setting of  the internal repository , right?

Comment: 1) Why do you care about unused jars in the repository? 2) Not exactly. Nexus manages multiple repositories of different types. If you don't want it to proxy some or all outside repos, then you need to configure a specific repository or repository group in Nexus appropriately, and use that as the repo in your pom. For example, you're currently referring to the "public" repository group. If you simply remove all the proxied repos from that group, then the behavior you're talking about will stop completely.

Comment: I now have some idea about how the Nexus repository works.Thanks for the insight given

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure it in your repository software (Artifactory, Nexus, ...).

I think you have set up a proxy repository here which downloads every artefact requested. You might want to try running a 'hosted repository' instead. More info [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-manage-repo.html).

The equivalent concept in Artifactory is a 'local repository' (read [here](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Understanding+Repositories)).

Comment: A hosted repository is just a "normal" maven repo. That won't help in retrieving artifacts from third-party repos.

Comment: This is what exactly they don't want to happen (as I can understand from the question). They don't want the dependencies to be downloaded to their internal repository, using it as a place to put company's internal artefacts only.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the dependencies you need manually using following command. It will add the package to your local repository such that you can use it. Read [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```